# How can i rewrite this sql script without using exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to sql. How can i rewrite the below script without using exists

```sql
select
  distinct oe.*,
  o.*,
  so.*,
  ro.*
from
  ms_bvoip_order_extension oe
  inner join ms_order o on oe.ms_order_id = o.ms_order_id
  inner join ms_sub_order so on so.ms_order_id = o.ms_order_id
  inner join ms_job j on j.entity_id = so.ms_sub_order_id
  inner join ms_task t on t.wf_job_id = j.wf_job_id
where
  o.order_type = 900
  and o.entered_date between to_date('12/01/2018 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  and to_date('12/31/2018 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  and j.entity_type = 5
  and exists (
    select
      'X'
    from
      ms_task t
    where
      (
        (t.name like '%Error%')
        or (t.name like '%Correct%')
        or (t.name = '%Create AOTS Ticket%')
      )
      and t.job_id = hextoraw(j.wf_job_id)
  )
order by
  o.usrp_order_number;
```

Comment: Why can't you use `exists`? It does work for `mysql`, which is the tag you have, according to (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: Does the current query return correct results?

Answer (score 1):

As Jerry mentioned, you **can** use EXISTS but if you don't want to you could JOIN the same EXISTS subquery:

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT hextoraw(j.wf_job_id) JOB_ID 
    FROM ms_task 
    WHERE t.name like '%Error%' 
        or t.name like '%Correct%' 
        or t.name like '%Create AOTS Ticket%'
    ) TASK ON t.job_id = TASK.JOB_ID
```

You could probably remove your other ms_task table and JOIN ON `j.wf_job_id`......

Comment: I think this works and is faster.  Let us know Alan

Comment: Now that I look at it again, shouldn't this be a LIKE instead of equals? `t.name = '%Create AOTS Ticket%'`